# E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: course in "UPDATE PersonalDetails SET course=?,percentage=?,name=?,email=? WHERE name='xv'"

Tags: android, kotlin, sqliteopenhelper

When I update datas in my table I'm getting this error in my coding. How to solve this issue

val success = db.update(TABLE_PERSONALDETAILS, contentValues, KEY_NAME + "=" + "'"+ stud.name +"'", null)

Can you please help me to solve this issue

Comment: what kind of help do you need? your error is clear and obvius, says that there is `no such column` and you didn't even posted column names, db creation and handling, `contentValues` structure etc. voting for close, "Needs debugging details"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.